# Delay when updating UILabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, delay

**Background:**

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass (`AlbumCell`), which in turn has two subclasses (`Type1AlbumCell and Type2AlbumCell`).  `AlbumCell` acts only as an abstract class, while the latter two are laid out as prototype cells in a `UITableViewController` within a storyboard.  `AlbumCell` declares two `IBOutlets`, `likeCountLabel` and `shortTitleLabel`, which each subclass connects two via its layout as a prototype cell in the storyboard.

**Problem:**

There is a delay when updating the text for either label in `Type2AlbumCell`, while `Type1AlbumCell` updates immediately upon setting the values.  *This is not the result of the main thread being held up*, since you can scroll and perform other actions while you are waiting for the text to update. It just takes 4-5 seconds or so.  Has anyone experienced something like this before?  Thanks.

Please keep in mind, the text is being set from within the cell subclasses, not from within the table view controller.  This problem occurs when we are trying to update label text while a cell is currently being viewed, not when setting up a new cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  A button is tapped in the cell subclass that causes the text to change.

Comment: This is difficult to say anything about without code to accompany it.

Comment: post code, you have tried so far.

Comment: "Delay" of 4-5 seconds just about _always_ means you are running this code on a background thread. Don't.

Comment: @matt Thanks! Turns out you are right.  I am going to explain what happened in an official answer to my question.

Comment: I believe I already explained it. :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I was making a call to UIKit from a completion block that was running on a background thread.  Initially, I had ruled this out as the cause of the problem, because another piece of code in the completion block was called immediately.  I had not realized that calling UIKit from a background thread could lead to erratic behavior, because UIKit is not thread safe.

Fortunately, I can still call UIKit from the completion block, so long as I make sure that code is running on the main thread.  I do this using the following code I found in another Stack Overflow question:

```
- (void)runBlockOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking:(void (^)(void))block {
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    block();
} else {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
}}
```

This method allows you to pass a block of code to be executed on the main thread, without deadlocking the main thread if you are already running on the main thread.  This works most of the time, but apparently has some edge cases.

You can also use `performSelectorOnMainThread:`

Comment: I don't understand what you think is gained by the `isMainThread` test. Nor do I understand what you think is gained by the `dispatch_sync`. The way to guarantee execution on the main thread harmlessly is `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...`. There is no danger of deadlock. Why are you making things hard for yourself?